# How Can I Change File Explorer's Default View to "Details" and Group by Type Using CMD/Batch or PowerShell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-explorer, cmd.exe, windows-registry

I'm looking to customize the default settings of File Explorer on my Windows 10 system. Specifically, I want to set the default view mode to "Details" and have files always grouped by "Type". I want to achieve this through Command Prompt (cmd/batch) or PowerShell scripting.

#### What I Have Tried:

I have looked into some [relevant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gppref/3c837e92-016e-4148-86e5-b4f0381a757f) register keys, for example:

```
reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

or

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced"
```

However, I am unsure which one(s) I should modify and to what values.

#### My Question:

How can I script the changes to make the "Details" view and "Group by Type" the default settings for all folders in File Explorer? Can specific registry keys or PowerShell commands be used to achieve this?

I understand that these settings might be managed per folder and that Windows may override them in certain cases, but any guidance on making a global change would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just set this to a top level folder (options) and then apply to all folders?  That is what  I do.

Comment: There are various defined folder types,. such as *General items*, *Documents*, and *Music*. For each of those types, one can define a view (e.g., *Details*), the sorting order, the *Group by* field. In addition, one can define the columns (e.g., in *Music*, add *Title*, or in *Pictures*, *Frame width*). Once that is done for all folder type, **all** Explorer windows will open to those specs **unless one changes the view**.

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Need help decoding registry binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451366/need-help-decoding-registry-binary-data)
contains an outstanding
[answer by Keith Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451366/need-help-decoding-registry-binary-data/61240563#61240563),
from which I quote this small part:

> Once a folder has been viewed in Explorer, Windows saves the view
> settings for that individual folder under two registry keys. If the
> folders are local, the keys are:
>
> ```
> HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
> ```
>
> --- and ---
>
> ```
> HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
> ```

You may set your registry settings to be the way you want and
then export them to `.reg` file that can then import into any
computer user. You may also use only some of the settings.